# Having multiple button with Same Id to bind jquerymobile in Phonegap

Tags: android, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am having many pages in my Phonegap android app. Sometime I would like to come back to previous page. So I am planning add one back button in all pages. In such case I need to have many buttons with different id and I need bind all those id's with event Listener. 
To overcome this , Can I have same Id for all  the buttons , So that I will have to bind the only one id and perform require action in the function. Or suggest me some better idea to overcome this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First there's already an easy way to add a back button to your pages. just add this attribute:

```
data-add-back-btn="true"
```

to your page div with **`data-role="page"`** and jQuery mobile will automatically generate you a back button.

Official documentation can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jpJH4/

Or there's another solution, if you want to choose a location of back buttons you can create buttons and add this attribute to them (no need for href):

```
data-rel="back"
```

It will automatically server as a back button.

```
<a data-role="button" data-rel="back">Back</a>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fs3j3/